# I wan to have an image function that can be extracted from the google drive link. URL of an image in the form of google drive link

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a massive data of 700 objects with the description only in column A. I want to get the images of those 700 object cells description. Somehow I have managed to get the links of all those objects into each cell through google drive in column B. Now I want the images to be shown in the column c.

the below function is not working for extraction of an image through drive link:
=Image(url,1)  , =image(B2) , arrayformula etc.
Can someone tell me the how to extract the image from the link.

Comment: `image` - [Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?sjid=11857366940370801557-AP): You can only use URLs that **aren't** hosted at drive.google.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How display images from Google Drive on Gsheet cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287504/how-display-images-from-google-drive-on-gsheet-cell)