# How to replace text by using Google scripts?

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to show an image from Google Drive in a Google Spreadsheet. 
I have to replace the text: 
         `open?`
for: 
         `uc?export=download&`
in the Shareable link:
         `https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwJUnx7uETDmaG42eGdEVUVocU0`

I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/42819032/2661411:

"
I made a two lines script to use the share link of an image in Google Drive.

1. Go to Tools > Script editor.
2. Copy, paste the following code
3. Click on run for permission

   `function DRIVE_IMAGE(link){
       prefix_url = "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&";
       link.replace("open?", "uc?export=download&");
   }`

Using the script :

1. Copy the share link of your image in Google Drive.
2. Go to a cell
3. Enter the formula `=IMAGE(DRIVE_IMAGE("COPIED_LINK"))` "

But didn't work for me, it said:

`TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined. (line 3, file "ImgView")`

Any ideas? I would like it to keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<<IMAGE ID>>`. Refer the below formula.

```
=image("https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0BwJUnx7uETDmaG42eGdEVUVocU0")
```

**Script**

```
/**
 * @customfunction
 */
function DRIVE_IMAGE(link){
   var newLink = link.replace("https://drive.google.com/open?", "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&");
   return newLink;
}
```

Now, you can use the formula `=IMAGE(DRIVE_IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwJUnx7uETDmaG42eGdEVUVocU0"))`

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do... but how? (I need a script)

Comment: @isk27 I have added the script

Comment: Is there any way to make a range selection? for example, I got a column with all the links to the images in the Drive and in the next column the formula that gets the correct link from the other column in the same row?