# Get "Image in cell" URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a Google Spreadsheet with an image that has been **inserted into a cell**. I need to access the URL of this image from Google Apps Script. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) only seems to cover OverGridImage which are images that can be moved around. My image has been inserted into a cell.

I have tried this code, but it doesn't return images that have been inserted into a cell.

```
var images = sheet.getImages();

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  Logger.log(images[i].getAnchorCell().getRow());
}
```

The [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) has some methods for getting the background, but this is for colour, not images.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12oysJsWS62Dw9ZLzZh7Fd-oYx-LYIoc-m3mUPUT7Wc4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. I check it. But it seems that the image doesn't have the URL. Can I ask you about the method for putting this image? I thought that from the method, the workaround might be able to be thought.

Comment: @Tanaike In the google sheet, go to Insert > Image > Image In Cell

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, the URL cannot be retrieved from the images putting with such method, yet. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Tanaike is this because Google has not updated the API?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. I thought that although the current API cannot achieve it yet, the possibility that it can achieve in the future cannot be denied.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you, I understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely this (insert image INTO a cell) is too new and the API isn't ready.  But, the alternative is to encode/decode the image in base64 and store them that way.  That's what I'm doing now instead since I realized the insertImage method does what you just said.  Insert images over the entire spreadsheet as opposed to the cell.

Comment: Can I still display the image nicely in Google Sheets using this method? I want the end user to be able to see the image in the cell as it is displayed when using "Image in Cell"

Comment: No, you'll just see a base64 string.  Actually, I realize my method isn't the best.  Each cell has a 50kb limit, and I'm resorting to LZW compression to get larger files in there.  However, for my purposes, this is ok.  But, I did come across this thread that you might find useful.  The guy is inserting images from his Google Drive folder into the cell:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26801041/what-is-the-right-way-to-put-a-drive-image-into-a-sheets-cell-programmatically